# How to save cell value in datagridview into a list<list<>>

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I have a problem but i don't know how to solve it.
i have a datagridview like this picture
[image]

as you can see, there are two (A->1, A->2, A->3) and (B->1, B->2, B->3)
i want to save it like this to write to a text file, i want to save like this
A { {4.5,4.2,4.3};  {1.2,1.5,1.8} }   and B { {4.3,1.8,1.9}, {2.2,2.3,4.5}}
but i don't know how to solve it with datagridview C# winform.
Can anybody help me ? Thank you so much.

Comment: what if you have 7 rows of A, the top 4 are `1-4` and the last 3 are `1-3`?

Comment: BTW, if you have the rows in a fixed order, it may be solvable but if it has a random order, then the rule here is not clear and also not enough to guide us what to do.

Comment: Yes , @King King ,Firstly , I think he needs to sort with `Chemical` and `Place` :)

Comment: Actually, it is like this. You have three input: Chemical, Place and Replication. Such as: you have two Chemicals{A,B}, three Places {1,2,3} and Replication =2. So, you will have data like above picture. Do you understand ?

Answer (score 0):

This could be helpful:
[Reading from .txt file, then exporting data to DataGridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16498614/reading-from-txt-file-then-exporting-data-to-datagridview)

It is for reading the textfile.
But for saving, I believe you could code it "in reverse" :)

Answer (score 0):

```
//Ok, this should work.

//First, represent the datagridview in a more readeable List
class My_row
{
    public My_row(string Chemical, int Place, double Height)
    {
        this.Chemical = Chemical;
        this.Place = Place;
        this.Height = Height;
    }

    public string Chemical;
    public int Place;
    public double Height;
}

//then, the datagridview is this
List<My_row> rows = new List<My_row>;

foreach(var row in datagridview.rows)
{
    My_row my_row = new My_row(
        (string)row.Cells[0].value, 
        (int)row.Cells[1].value, 
        (double)row.Cells[2].value)
}
//with this you can loop the data easier plus you can use LINQ to order, filter and find the data in the datagridview

//Now, represent your final data structure

//In this case you have groups of 3 values of places 1, 2 and 3.
class Group
{
    double value_1;
    double value_2;
    double value_3;
}

//this groups of 3 values are in a bigger group that is the chemical.
class Chemical
{
    char name;
    List<Group> groups;
}

//finally your file is going to be a list of chemical
List<chemical> chemical_list;

//now you have to fill that list, then loop through it to write the file.
char previous_chemical = rows[0].chemical;//initial chemical letter
Chemical chemical = new Chemical();
chemical.name = rows[0].chemical;//initial chemical letter
Group group = new Group();
foreach(My_row row in rows)
{
    if(row.Chemical != previous_chemical)
    {
        previous_chemical = chemical.name;
        chemical_list.Add(chemical);
        chemical = new chemical();
        chemical.name = row.Chemical;
    }

    if(row.Place == 1){ group.value_1 = row.Height; }
    if(row.Place == 2){ group.value_2 = row.Height; }
    if(row.Place == 3)
    {
        group.value_3 = row.Height;
        chemical.Add(group);
        group = new Group();
    }
}

//That was he hard work. Now you have to loop the list (Chemicals, Groups and values) and write the file.
```