# how to import txt file into datagridview in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I want code C# to import txt.file into datagridview

file txt.file me
[image]

code me datagridview show one columns
[image]

Comment: Don't use image when you post the code.

Comment: I think ans is available here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26753914/import-data-from-text-file-and-display-in-datagrid/

Comment: Read your text file line by line then parse your line into your Model/Object and at the end bind list of object that you make after parsing with Grid

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Import data from text file and display in datagrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26753914/import-data-from-text-file-and-display-in-datagrid)

Answer (score 1):

I have done this on button click event.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("D:\\test.txt");
            string[] columnnames = file.ReadLine().Split(' ');
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            foreach (string c in columnnames)
            {
                dt.Columns.Add(c);
            }
            string newline;
            while ((newline = file.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                string[] values = newline.Split(' ');
                for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
                {
                    dr[i] = values[i];
                }
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            }
            file.Close();
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        }
```

Here is text file :
[image: text.txt]

And here is output :

[image]

Just update according to your need. Define Column name in text file or default in grid view

Comment: It ought to be Split('\t')

Answer (score 0):

First of all replace `Split(' ')` with `Split(',')`.

If the separator is tabulation use:

```
Split(new string[] { "\\tab" }, StringSplitOptions.None)
```

Comment: Its not split by ",".

Comment: It ought to be Split('\t')