# how to import items from txt to listview c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm new at C# still learning I'm coding a bulk mail sender application, I want to import mail address from txt file to list view for example

```
  No | Email Address |
  1    test1@gmail.com
  2    test2@gmail.com
  3    test3@gmail.com
  4    test4@gmail.com
  5    test5@gmail.com
```

I not typed any code for this because Idk how to do that but I explained what I want to do I'll add a photo too

[image]

I need a sample code, when I click import open a txt file and import email addresses to "Email Address" Columns

Thanks

Comment: okay bro sorry I'll keep searching then

Comment: Check this it similar ur question.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45317617/how-to-import-txt-file-into-datagridview-in-c-sharp

Comment: _I not typed any code for this because Idk how to do that_ - perhaps try some console application with simple problems/games first. That way you'll learn the basics of input/output, basic programming concepts and basic understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try *querying* the file; assuming that UI is *WinForms* you can put something like this:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

...

var itemsToAdd = File
  .ReadLines(@"c:\ItemsToCreate.txt")
  .Skip(1)                            // Skip Caption   
  .Select(line => line.Split(         // Split each line 
        new char[] { ' ', '\t' },     // .. by tabulations and spaces
        StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries) // .. while dropping empty chunks
     .LastOrDefault())                // take the last chunk (or null) from the split    
  .Where(email => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(email)) // filter out null or empty emails 
  .Select(email => new ListViewItem(email)) // create a ListViewItem from email
  .ToArray();                         // materialize list view items into an array 

listView1.Items.AddRange(itemsToAdd);
```