# DataGrid TSV file with dynamic columns

Tags: c#, wpf, csv, wpfdatagrid

I am trying to create a DataGrid in WPF, in order to make an editor for some tab separated files. The first line of the TSV contains the columns. Also after some research, I found this code 
[Import data from text file and display in datagrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26753914/import-data-from-text-file-and-display-in-datagrid)
which works pretty good, but, when the file is loaded the window becomes unresponsive. Or when I try to resize the window (or scroll down) again the same, it takes time to load it
This is from MainWindow.xaml

```
 <DataGrid x:Name="dtGrid" Grid.Row="1" AutoGenerateColumns="True" ItemsSource="{Binding}"/>
```

Mainwindow.cs

```
dtGrid.DataContext = Helper.DataTableFromTextFile("tsv.txt", '\t');
```

PS. I also tried this too.

```
dtGrid.ItemsSource = Helper.DataTableFromTextFile("tsv.txt", '\t').DefaultView;
```

Any ideas?

EDIT:

```
<Window x:Class="MyFileEdit.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyFileEdit"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="File Edit" Height="350" Width="525" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="16*" MinHeight="16" MaxHeight="16"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="303*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <DataGrid x:Name="dtGrid" Grid.Row="1" AutoGenerateColumns="True" ItemsSource="{Binding}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: For the record, `DataGridView`, `DataGrid` and `GridView` are all different controls.

Comment: You have probably disabled the UI virtualization somehow. Please post your full XAML markup: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve