# Insert into Array List

Tags: c#, arraylist

I am very new to programming thank you for your time. I believe I have searched far and wide. I found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16498614/reading-from-txt-file-then-exporting-data-to-datagridview

This works great on what I am doing - Below I call the class and read though the file . This all works great. 
It displays all of the read file information in the DataGrid. 
I am now wanting to insert a record (this is where I am completly lost). I have read plenty of how to's on how to insert a record into a list but based on how this code is below .I see no way on how to insert a record.

I must be looking left when looking right. Thank you for any guidance. 
My Class.

```
public class User {
  public string Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string Surname { get; set; }
  public string Telephone { get; set; }
  public bool Vip { get; set; }
  public int Age { get; set; }
  public decimal Balance { get; set; }

  public static List<User> LoadUserListFromFile(string path) {
    var users = new List<User>();

    foreach (var line in File.ReadAllLines(path)) {
      var columns = line.Split('\t');
      users.Add(new User {
        Id = columns[0],
        Name = columns[1],
        Surname = columns[2],
        Telephone = columns[3],
        Vip = columns[4] == "1",
        Age = Convert.ToInt32(columns[5]),
        Balance = Convert.ToDecimal(columns[6])
      });
    }

    return users;
  }
}
```

This is how I load it from the Main Form.

```
usersDataGridView.DataSource = User.LoadUserListFromFile("user_db.txt");
```

Comment: "The array"? Add the code fragment that illustrates what you tried to do or using pseudo code if you must, to show what it is that you are specifically having trouble with.

Comment: I see I keep getting down voted. I am unsure of how to even ask the question if I am not asking it right above.

Comment: I see you have the `Informed` badge, meaning you read the entire tour page, which is commendable. If you had read [how do i ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), you would have known that your original (unedited) question was not a good one. I am glad you decided to edit it and be clearer about what you are having trouble with, which appears to be either "how do I insert a new row in a DataGridView" or "how can I bind a list to a DataGridView as the datasource". You may want to [edit] your question again to specify what it is that you want to achieve.

Comment: In the mean time, for inspiration, you may want to have a look at [C# Tutorial - Binding a DataGridView to a Collection](http://tech.pro/tutorial/776/csharp-tutorial-binding-a-datagridview-to-a-collection)

Comment: Thank you for your Time Alex. I have been trying for 2 weeks and just cannot find anything to help me.. along with trying to figure out how to ask a question and ask it correctly with not to much code or information as I see some don't like. Again thanks for the guidance I will read through what you linked.

Comment: For the "insert" have a look at this example: http://www.dotnetperls.com/datagridview-add-rows

Answer (score 0):

After much searching I found the solution for me here
[How to bind a List<string> to a DataGridView control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/479329/how-to-bind-a-liststring-to-a-datagridview-control) - The solution by Sudeep.

I bound to my datagrid like such and then did my insert. This is what worked for me.

```
BindingSource gridDataBinder = new BindingSource();
gridDataBinder.DataSource = usersDataGridView.DataSource;
dgDataBeingProcessed.DataSource = gridDataBinder;
gridDataBinder.Insert(rowIndex, new User(){.. etc.;
```