# How split space to fill dataGridView from file .txt in C#

Tags: c#

I need help :-)

I have a file.txt with content like below :

```
00001    JhonKey     023301923
00002    Hercules    023039910
```

I want to load this file to datagridview through datatable and the result should be saved in a datagrid like below :

```
COL1    |    COL2      |  COL3
-----------------------------------
00001   |    JhonKey   | 023301923
00002   |    Hercules  | 023039910
```

I'm trying this code :

```
 using (StreamReader SR = new StreamReader(txtFileName)) 
        {
            int row = 0;
            string line;
            while ((line = SR.ReadLine())!= null)
            {
                string[] Columns = line.Split(',');
                dataGridView2.Rows.Add();
                for (int i = 0; i < Columns.Length; i++)
                {
                    dataGridView2[i, row].Value = Columns[i];
                }
                row++;
            }
        }
```

but the result is not as expected. It looks wrong, everything is wirtten in the first column, shown below :

```
COL1                         |    COL2      |  COL3
--------------------------------------------------------
00001   JhonKey   023301923  |              |
00002   Hercules  023039910  |              |
```

Comment: you mean use break point ?

Comment: great this works, but i must create split space to the tune of space which use on file.txt

Comment: Look in my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take look on line string[] Columns = line.Split(','); 
You try to split line by comma, but no commas in the file. Try split by space.
Like

```
string[] Columns = line.Split(' ');
```

Or

```
string[] Columns = line.Split(new []{' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

Comment: great this works, but i must create split space to the tune of space which use on file.txt like below :
string[] Columns = line.Split('               ');

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Data;
using System.IO;


public class FromYourFileToGrid
{

 public static DataTable DataTableFromYourTextFile(string directory, char splitter=',')
 {
     DataTable result;

     string[] LineArray = File.ReadAllLines(directory);

     result = FormDataTable(LineArray, splitter);

     return result;
 }


 private static DataTable FormDataTable(string []LineArray, char splitter)
 {
     bool IsHeaderSet = false;

     DataTable dt = new DataTable();

     AddColumnToTable(LineArray, splitter, ref dt);

     AddRowToTable(LineArray, splitter, ref dt);

     return dt;
 }


 private static void AddRowToTable(string []valueCollection, char splitter, ref DataTable dt)
 {

     for (int i = 1; i < valueCollection.Length; i++)
     {
     string[] values = valueCollection[i].Split(splitter);

     DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();

     for (int j = 0; j < values.Length; j++)
     {
         dr[j] = values[j];
     }

     dt.Rows.Add(dr);
     }
 }


 private static void AddColumnToTable(string []columnCollection, char splitter, ref DataTable dt)
 {
     string[] columns = columnCollection[0].Split(splitter);

     foreach (string columnName in columns)
     {
     DataColumn dc = new DataColumn(columnName, typeof(string));
     dt.Columns.Add(dc);
     }

 }

}
```

You added coloumns and rows in the same loop. This is false way to create grid. You should add rows and coloumns in the differents method.Above class will create your grid and then add coloumn, rows to your grid.You can call above class's methods with :

```
dataGridView1.DataSource =       FromYourFileToGrid.DataTableFromYourTextFile("file.txt", '|');
```

And then your datas will be added coloumns and rows correctly. And u should read more and more tutorial. Because this questions were asked in Stackoverflow.You can read this [Reading from .txt file, then exporting data to DataGridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16498614/reading-from-txt-file-then-exporting-data-to-datagridview) question. I hope this code help you.