# Populate DataGridView upon load?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I would like to populate a row in DataGridView when the form loads up. I have tried this:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    dataGridView1.DataBindingComplete += dataGridView1_DataBindingComplete;
}

private void dataGridView1_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
{
    string[] row = new string[] { "1", "Product 1", "1000" };
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

}

but it doesn't seem to be working. Could somebody please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using it the wrong way. If you are using data binding, you should not be adding a row manually. You can add this data row to your data source, instead of adding it to dataGridView.Rows

You can read the lines from a File, as shown below

```
string[] readText = File.ReadAllLines(path);
```

You have two options to add these lines to the dataGridView1.

1. Unbound

Loop through the array and add to the rows.

2. Bound

Add information to a binding source and bind to the dataGridView1

You can view a working sample here [Reading from .txt file, then exporting data to DataGridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16498614/reading-from-txt-file-then-exporting-data-to-datagridview)

Comment: Sorry, I do not follow. My eventual aim is to parse a text file and add rows to the table, one for each line of the file. I am trying to learn how to implement this.

Comment: Ah thank you. One final question, in the link you provided there is a method called Test_1() actually adding the data to the rows. Where should this method called from? (I haven't done GUI development for a while- seeing partial classes confuses me a bit)

Comment: @user997112 You can call it in your constructor or Form Load.